# Android + compatibility library ListFragment not running Adapter getView() method?

Tags: android

I'm aware of the setListShown(false) and setListShown(true) issue when using the Compatibility Library with ListFragments, but how do I display a ListFragment regardless of this bug?  My ArrayAdapter getView() method never fires for some reason...

Bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17096

**DateAdapter.java**

```
class DateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DateVO> {

    //constructor
    public DateAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("tag", "getView"); //never called
        ...
```

**MyFragment.as**

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<DateVO>> {
...
    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            m_adapter = new DateAdapter(context);
            setListAdapter(m_adapter);
            //setListShown(false);

            //initialize the loader
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }
...
```

Comment: Any suggestions at all are appreciated!  This one has me stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got this to load content from my custom loader... finally!  And since setListShown(true|false) doesn't work properly with the compatibility lib, 
I simply created a custom ProgressDialog added via a DialogFragment.  If you wish to see code just respond and I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have found a way around this.   For the future, if you are using the support compatibility library, you might want to try getSupportLoaderManager().